# Why can't I apply sort_values to a dataframe more than once?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Say for example I have a multi-column dataframe. I want to arrange my data by sorting column `a` ascending first, then by column `b` ascending also.

I am able to achieve this by the ff. code: `df.sort_values(['b','a'])`. Note the reversed order of the arguments.

My question is, why doesn't `df.sort_values('a').sort_values('b')` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.sort_values(['a', 'b'])` you are first sorting the dataframe by the column `a`, and then *within* those sortings, sorting by `b`. Think of it almost as grouping by the first sort, then sorting *within* those groupings. If there was a `c`, it would sort the `c` column *within* the `a` `b` groups.

If you do `.sort_values('a').sort_values('b')` you are sorting the dataframe by `a` and then taking that returned dataframe, and "starting over" by sorting it by `b` basically destroying the previous sorting of `a`. using `['a', 'b']` keeps each of the sorts and sorts within.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation! As for the first case, the keyword that explains is "within".

Comment: anytime! I'm glad that helps.